# Comparison test of an improper integral?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Determine whether the integral is divergent or convergent.

$ \int_{30}^\infty \dfrac{x\sqrt{x}+x}{1-x^3}$

I have been stuck on the following integral for a few days now, I asked the teacher for help with no hope. The question is a sub-question of other integrals that are solved with the comparison test. However, I cannot use the comparison test here, as the function is negative in the interval of the integration.

I tried to expand the function into a sum of quotient, but it looked even worse.
According to the solution manual, it is supposed to be convergent, but I cannot for the life of me understand how I supposed to think.

Comment: $\frac{x+x\sqrt x}{1-x^3}\sim \frac{1}{x^{3/2}}$ at $\infty $.

Answer (score 1):

That integral converges if and only if the integral$$\int_{30}^\infty\frac{x\sqrt x+x}{x^3-1}\,\mathrm dx\tag1\label{I}$$converges. And now you *can* apply the comparison test:$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{x\sqrt x+x}{x^3-1}}{\frac1{x\sqrt x}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^3+x^2\sqrt x}{x^3-1}=1.$$Since the integral$$\int_{30}^\infty\frac1{x\sqrt x}\,\mathrm dx$$converges, then so does $\eqref{I}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! That helped a lot!